# Different urls point to different directories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4

If I go for `http://example.com` then its pointing to `/var/www/html`

Now I am in need that if I go for `http://example.com/dashboard` then it will point to `/var/www/example/public`. Or If this not possible then `/var/www/html/example/public` would also be okay.

And again I need that if I go for `http://wildcardsubdomain.example.com/` then also it will point to  `/var/www/example/public`. Or If this not possible then `/var/www/html/example/public` would also be okay.

How can I make so?

I have tried with this but `/dashboard` not working:

```
ServerName example.com
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
UseCanonicalName Off
#dynamic subdomain provisioning
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #WORKING
    ServerName user.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #NOT WORKING
    ServerName www.example.com/dashboard
    ServerAlias *.example.com/dashboard
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Not very sure but you may try proxy server like nginx ?

Comment: Your user.example.com settings should work but www.example.com/dashboard one won't. You need to handle /dashboard via an htacces inside /var/www/html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `dashboard` I could solve that using the [Alias Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /dashboard /var/www/example/public
    <Directory /var/www/example/public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```